# Moving Laravel 5 application to Lumen - Class path.storage does not exist error

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, lumen-5.2

I'm trying to port my laravel 5 based api application to lumen however its giving me this error consistently and I'm at my wits end on how to solve it. This is the error stack:

```
[Sun Mar 13 14:44:27.424346 2016] [:error] [pid 4683] [client 127.0.0.1:51632] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class path.storage does not exist' in /home/Projects/api.local/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:736
Stack trace:
#0 /home/Projects/api.local/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(736): ReflectionClass->__construct('path.storage')
#1 /home/Projects/api.local/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(631): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build('path.storage', Array)
#2 /home/Projects/api.local/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Application.php(203): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make('path.storage', Array)
#3 /home/Projects/api.local/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminatesearch?utf8=✓&q=path.storage&type=Issues/Foundation/helpers.php(63): Laravel\\Lumen\\Application->make('path.storage', Array)
#4 /home/Projects/api.local/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php(633): app('path.storage')
#5 /home/Projects/api.local in /home/Projects/api.local/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 736
```

This is my composer file:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/lumen-framework": "5.2.*",
    "illuminate/support": "5.2.*",
    "vlucas/phpdotenv": "~2.2",
    "cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable": "dev-master",
    "nanigans/single-table-inheritance": "dev-master",
    "kalnoy/nestedset": "dev-master",
    "laravelbook/ardent": "3.*",
    "dingo/api": "1.0.*@dev",
    "codesleeve/laravel-stapler": "1.0.*",
    "laravel/socialite": "^2.0",
    "aws/aws-sdk-php": "2.4.*@dev",
    "sammyk/laravel-facebook-sdk": "^3.0",
    "intervention/image": "^2.3"
},
```

I've just added some routes to my route file and already I'm facing this error - please how can I fix this?

Comment: Have you grepped your codebase for "path.storage" or "storage_path"? Something somewhere is trying to get the path to the storage directory, likely via `app('path.storage')` or `storage_path()`. It may be one of the included packages, as well.

Comment: Also, just an FYI, the "codesleeve/laravel-stapler" package requires the entire "illuminate/laravel-framework" package. You may want to look into switching to the framework agnostic "codesleeve/stapler" package.